# TCP Port Exhaustion with WindowsAzure.Storage in .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, sockets, azure, tcp, azure-storage

I'm running the latest version of the WindowsAzure.Storage library, 6.1.1. This was previously a [known issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/08/08/net-clients-encountering-port-exhaustion-after-installing-kb2750149-or-kb2805227.aspx) but is supposed to have been fixed back in .NET 4.5.1. It's exactly the issue I'm having.

I'm hitting a table in Azure Storage with 100m+ rows to insert. I've focused on making the code fast and scalable, it maxes out an Azure D12 VM running Datacenter 2012 R2. I'm seeing 5,000 - 10,000 entities processed per second (read file, process, upload).

Update: This ONLY happens on Azure VMs. On my home system it doesn't occur.

**The process always crashes out at ~16,384 batches** (around 320,000 records) with a classic port exhaustion error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

I've done the usual things: increase MaxUserPort (64434) and decreased TcpTimedWaitDelay (15 seconds). **MaxUserPort seems to be ignored** given the suspiciously logical 16,384 it fails at.

**Netstat shows that the ports are never being closed in the first place.** The state on all of them remains 'Established' untill the process itself is closed, then they disappear.

The actual connection code comes down to:

```
var acx = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(conn);
var client = acx.CreateCloudTableClient();
var table = client.GetTableReference("Test");
var op = new TableBatchOperation();

foreach (var record in batch) //Batch is just a bunch of entity objects
    op.InsertOrReplace(record);

try
{
    await table.ExecuteBatchAsync(op, opsConfig, null);
    Interlocked.Add(ref totalUploaded, batch.Count);
}
catch...
```

I've tried every variation I can think of - reusing a pool of TableBatchOperations, having a single table/client/account to creating an object for every hit, and every combination in between.

The problem seems to be lower level than I can get to. When the issue was supposedly fixed two years ago the connections were staying open because the response stream wasn't being read properly.

Grateful for any suggestions! Please just ask if you need more information or clarification.

Comment: Are any of those methods disposable?

Comment: Sadly they're not! They don't expose the underlying connection / socket either.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of `CloudStorageAccount`? It would save us a lot of time.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.cloudstorageaccount.aspx

Comment: I hit a similar problem several years ago when pumping up the parallelism of my client code. It turned out that TCP Ports are not closed by the OS when you close them in .net. I'd like to point at a reference for this, but its escaped me (this has a tangential reference though https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx). The solution was to accept that a TCP Port connection is a long running thing and carry out internal application pooling of them. Using Dispose patterns just didn't close the underlying port. If I remember its actually part of the Windows OS spec.

Comment: Hi Phillip, thanks for your comment. The high parallelism is a common factor. I've been at this one for the last 10 hours and came across the same article - the wait time is dropped to 5 seconds but has no impact. Interestingly, this issue is absolutely specific to Azure. Reducing the wait time parameter did work for my home system where I saw, as you note, connections staying open with status TIME_WAIT after disposing. On Azure they stay ESTABLISHED.